# Pickle data was truncated while loading a numpy object

Tags: python, numpy, google-colaboratory, pickle

When I try to upload a large numpy object like this, on Google Collab:

`data = np.load('sample_data/train_data.npy', allow_pickle = True)`

I get an error:

`UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated`

I get no such error when I try to do it on my local system. I have uploaded `train_data.npy` in the Collab notebook. Also, the other answers on this site, related to the same error, do not seem to apply to my particular case.

Comment: Can you compare the file size locally and uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what caused the error, but uploading the `numpy` object on Google Drive and accessing it through Drive fixed the problem.

Give access to Drive by running this code:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

And load the data as follows:

`data = np.load('drive/MyDrive/train_data.npy', allow_pickle = True)`